# How to convert a floating point number to a string with max. 2 decimal digits in Delphi

Tags: delphi, floating-point, delphi-7

How can I convert a floating point number to a string with a maximum of **2 decimal digits** in **Delphi7**?

I've tried using:

```
 FloatToStrF(Query.FieldByName('Quantity').AsFloat, ffGeneral, 18, 2, FS);
```

But with the above, sometimes more than 2 decimal digits are given back, ie. the result is: 15,60000009

Comment: What about `Format('%3.2f', [yourFloatValue])`?

Comment: Or `str(myfloat:18:2,mystring)`

Answer (score 4):

Use `ffFixed` instead of `ffGeneral`.

`ffGeneral` ignores the `Decimal` parameter.

When you use `ffGeneral`, the `18` is saying that you want 18 significant decimal digits.  The routine will then express that number in the shortest manner, using scientific notation if necessary.  The `2` is ignored.

When you use `ffFixed`, you are saying you want `2` digits after the decimal point.

If you are wondering about why you sometimes get values that seem to be imprecise, there is much to be found on this site and others that will explain how floating-point numbers work.

In this case, `AsFloat` is returning a `double`, which like (most) other floating-point formats, stores its value in binary.  In the same way that 1/3 cannot be written in decimal with finite digits, neither can 15.6 be represented in binary in a finite number of bits.  The system chooses the closest possible value that can be stored in a `double`.  The exact value, in decimal, is:

15.5999999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375

If you had asked for 16 digits of precision, the value would've been rounded off to 15.6.  But you asked for 18 digits, so you get 15.5999999999999996.

Comment: Was this helpful at all?

Comment: Downvote because the question specifies "max 2 decimal digits". This answer *always* gives 2 decimal digits

Answer (score 1):

If you really mean what you write (MAX 2 decimal digits) and does not mean ALWAYS 2 decimal digits, then the two code snippets in the comments won't give you want you asked for (they will return a string that ALWAYS has two decimal digits, ie. ONE is returned as "1.00" (or "1,00" for Format depending on your decimal point).

If you truly want an option with MAX 2 decimal digits, you'll have to do a little post-processing of the returned string.

```
FUNCTION FloatToStrMaxDecimals(F : Extended ; MaxDecimals : BYTE) : STRING;
  BEGIN
    Result:=Format('%.'+IntToStr(MaxDecimals)+'f',[F]);
    WHILE Result[LENGTH(Result)]='0' DO DELETE(Result,LENGTH(Result),1);
    IF Result[LENGTH(Result)] IN ['.',','] THEN DELETE(Result,LENGTH(Result),1)
  END;
```

An alternative (and probably faster) implementation could be:

```
FUNCTION FloatToStrMaxDecimals(F : Extended ; MaxDecimals : BYTE) : STRING;
  BEGIN
    Result:=Format('%.'+IntToStr(MaxDecimals)+'f',[F]);
    WHILE Result[LENGTH(Result)]='0' DO SetLength(Result,PRED(LENGTH(Result)));
    IF Result[LENGTH(Result)] IN ['.',','] THEN SetLength(Result,PRED(LENGTH(Result)))
  END;
```

This function will return a floating point number with MAX the number of specified decimal digits, ie. one half with MAX 2 digits will return "0.5" and one third with MAX 2 decimal digits will return "0.33" and two thirds with MAX 2 decimal digits will return "0.67". TEN with MAX 2 decimal digits will return "10".

The final IF statement should really test for the proper decimal point, but I don't think any value other than period or comma is possible, and if one of these are left as the last character in the string after having stripped all zeroes from the end, then it MUST be a decimal point.

Also note, that this code assumes that strings are indexed with 1 for the first character, as it always is in Delphi 7. If you need this code for the mobile compilers in newer Delphi versions, you'll need to update the code. I'll leave that exercise up to the reader :-).

Comment: 1. Why do you not use `MaxDecimals` as an argument in the open array instead of including it in the string? 2. Calling Delete in a loop is unnecessarily slow. Better to find the position where you want to truncate and do the truncation a single time.

Comment: 1. No particular reason other than this is the way I think of it in my mind (IMO it makes it easier to read).
2. For the number of times this happens (the loop), I think the execution time is the least problem. But you are welcome to try to measure the time difference between DELETE and your suggestion :-). Maybe SetLength will be quicker than DELETE, since it mere truncates the length word in the prefix to the string data and does not re-allocate the string on the heap (which I think DELETE will do).
Anyway - premature optimization without profiling is not a good idea :-).

Comment: @HeartWare: using a better algorithm or function is not **premature** optimization. You first code a slow method that works, but then you start optimizing and removing overly slow code, until you have something that is presentable to the main public. Oh, and rather use `Format('%.*f', [MaxDecimals, F]);`. That is much easier to read.

Comment: Unless you can prove that it _is_ a "better algorithm", then - IMO - it _is_ *premature*. Also, "much easier to read" is a matter of taste. To me, it isn't easier to read. YMMV. Readability is more important than speed, unless the speed increase is significant in real world use (and not only in "now I call this function a gazillion times to prove that in this case, it is X milliseconds faster").

Comment: @HeartWare: All this nitpicking doesn't make a lot of sense and is unnecessary. Please try to accept what people say.

Comment: Not if I don't agree with it, and especially not in subjective matters (like "much easier to read").

Comment: You don't **agree** that using Delete this way is slow? That is not a matter of opinion, so agreement doesn't play a big role.

Comment: I have already acknowledged that the algorithm could be improved (speedwise), but this would diminish the readability of the function (IMO) and in these cases - to me - readability is more important than speed, unless (as I said) the speed increase is significant in real world use. I don't believe that any speed increase would be significant in real world use, so I opt for the (to me) more readable version. If you find the function to be less readable than a speed optimized version, then by all means use a speed optimized version. No one is preventing you from doing that...

Comment: If readability is important, then put the parts after DO and THEN on lines of their own. Using Delete like you do, using a while loop and an if is more, rather unreadable code.

Comment: Again - according to whom? You? Me? Readability is subjective. Putting the parts (when they are only one statement) after THEN and DO on seperate lines diminishes readability, since my eyes then have to dart all the way back to the left to read what should be done, whereas having it on the same line allows me to just read on in a normal left-to-right fashion...

Comment: According to me, yes. Readability is measurable, BTW. Using the standard coding conventions always makes code more readable than using your own.

Comment: "Using the standard coding conventions always makes code more readable than using your own." Not to me :-). Besides - "standard coding conventions" have changed over time. I am merely following one that predates the one you follow :-).

Answer (score 0):

i use this function in my application:

```
function sclCurrencyND(Const F: Currency; GlobalDegit: word = 2): Currency;
var R: Real; Fact: Currency;
begin
  Fact:= power(10, GlobalDegit);
  Result:= int(F*Fact)/Fact;
end;
```